# Remote Action in salesforce not working in safari but working in all other browsers

Tags: javascript, salesforce

Cannot call the remote method in the controller from the javascript.

**Code in JavaScript:**

```
Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                                                                '{!$RemoteAction.FitAssistenceController.updateObesityGoal}',
                                                                WeightValue,CaloriesValue,pastGoalRecommendedSteps,walkingSpeed,
                                                                function(result, event) {
                                                                   console.log("event",event);
                                                                    console.log("result",result);
                                                                }
                                                            );
```

**Remote Method:**

```
@RemoteAction 
    global static void updateObesityGoal(String weightGoal,String calChange,String RecommendedSteps,String walkingType){

/* perform the action */

}
```

This is working good in all the browsers except safari.

**Client side error is something like below:**

```
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://fitblissdev17-dev-ed--c.na40.visual.force.com/apexremote due to access control checks.
    request (VFRemote.js:42:137)
    request (VFRemote.js:74:225)
    doSend (VFRemote.js:96)
    combineAndSend (VFRemote.js:96:100)
    g (VFRemote.js:79:99)

[Error] Visualforce Remoting Exception: Unable to connect to the server (communication failure).
Object
Could not fetch properties. Object may no longer exist.
    error (VFRemote.js:117:461)
    (anonymous function) (VFRemote.js:134:160)
    fire (VFRemote.js:52)
    fireEvent (VFRemote.js:47:170)
    onProviderData (VFRemote.js:86:195)
    fire (VFRemote.js:52)
    fireEvent (VFRemote.js:47:170)
    onData (VFRemote.js:94:464)
    handleFailure (VFRemote.js:75:380)
    a (VFRemote.js:39:392)
    (anonymous function) (VFRemote.js:40:309)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are calling a JavaScript function on a button click?

If so, I would try with a true button:

```
<button type="button" onclick="remoteCall();">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: I am trying to call a method which in my Apex controller using the remote action functionality in Salesforce and this is working fine in all the browsers except safari.

Comment: What is firing the call to the controller? Is it a button click, document ready, etc.?

Comment: If this issue is browser specific, some HTML would be helpful.

Comment: `type="button"` is crucial in all WebKit browsers, including all iOS browsers (Safari, Chrome, Firefox for iOS, etc.) and Safari on a Mac (and probably on a PC too, although I didn't test it)

see here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/48731251/353145